# Typing hidden words with jQuery

Tags: jquery, keycode

I need a function that triggers an event every time every time a word is entered while the browser is focused on the webpage. I figured I'd use jQuery for this and came up with the following which does the job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var target = "808072727373767673738080";
   var input = "";

   $(window).delegate('*', 'keyup', function (e){
      input += e.keyCode;

      if(input==target){
         alert('philip');
      }

      if(e.keyCode==13){
         input = "";
      } 
   }); 
});
```

However I feel that there might be a simpler solution than to use the delegate function..
Any advice or links to other posts?

Comment: Does it work or not? If yes - why do you want to change something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give ID to body and use .keyup() for handling the event.
I think this must be more simpler way to do it.

Comment: True the cleaner solution is with the body:  $('body').keyup(function(e){ ... } Thanks!